# Java Comparator Interface

Tags: java, java-8, comparator, ocpjp

I have a misunderstanding about Comparator interface and its method compare 
here is the following code and i am wondering why compare method return -33 i believe that it should return 33

```
import java.util.*;
public class Sorted implements Comparable<Sorted>, Comparator<Sorted> {
private int num;
private String text;

Sorted(int n, String t) {
    this.num = n;
    this.text = t;
}

public String toString() {
    return "" + num;
}

public int compareTo(Sorted s) {
    return text.compareTo(s.text);
}

public int compare(Sorted s1, Sorted s2) {
    System.out.println(s1.num-s2.num); // return -33
    return s1.num - s2.num;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sorted s1 = new Sorted(88, "a");
    Sorted s2 = new Sorted(55, "b");
    TreeSet<Sorted> t1 = new TreeSet<>();
    t1.add(s1); t1.add(s2);
    TreeSet<Sorted> t2 = new TreeSet<>(s1);
    t2.add(s1); t2.add(s2);
    System.out.println(t1 + " " + t2);
    System.out.println(s1.num-s2.num); // prints 33
} }
```

Comment: The s1 and s2 in compare(Sorted s1, Sorted s2) are local variable definitions, you must not confuse them with the definitions in main(). It is not defined (algorithmically, only by the implementation) how TreeSet compares the two elements.

Comment: sure, i agree with you. but this is what i am trying to figure out (how TreeSet compares the tow element)

Answer (score 4):

You probably know that if `a-b=c` then `b-a=-c`.

What happens here is very similar. You seem to have assumed that `TreeSet` is calls the `compare` method like this:

```
comparator.compare(s1, s2)
```

(Note that I used `s1` and `s2` for demonstrative purposes. They are obviously not in scope in `TreeSet`. `s1` is the same instance as your `s1` and `s2` is the same instance as your s2`.)

But it could call `compare` like this as well:

```
comparator.compare(s2, s1)
```

couldn't it?

If it called it the second way, then the result of `-33` is to be expected.

EDIT:

I looked into the source code for `TreeSet.add` and found that it calls `TreeMap.put` with the item you are adding as the key. If you look further into `TreeMap.put`, you will find:

```
Comparator<? super K> cpr = comparator;
if (cpr != null) {
    do {
        parent = t;
        cmp = cpr.compare(key, t.key); // <--- "key" is the key passed into this method
                                       // "t" is an element that is already in the map
        if (cmp < 0)
            t = t.left;
        else if (cmp > 0)
            t = t.right;
        else
            return t.setValue(value);
    } while (t != null);
}
```

This shows that `TreeSet` indeed calls `compare` the way I described.

EDIT:

As Holger said in the comments, you should not implement `Comparator` by subtracting the two integers. Instead, you should use `Integer.compare`:

```
return Integer.compare(s1.num, s2.num);
```

In fact, there is no need to implement `Comparator` at all, you can pass in a `Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.num)` when you create the `TreeMap`:

```
TreeSet<Sorted> t1 = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.num));
```

Comment: i agree with you but in some other programs it calls it the normal way and not viceversa , how do i know how the Treeset calls compare method

Comment: @user2780962 You don't need to know that, unless you are trying to write a `TreeSet` yourself. In the `compare` method, your only job is to compare the two objects. You shouldn't depend on the order of arguments. If you are just curious, I have added some of the source code that shows how `compare` is called.

Comment: @user2780962 What you need to understand, is that you **can't** rely on any order. You have to provide a good comparator, that's all.

Comment: @user2780962 Did my answer answer your question? If so, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: Besides that, you should not use minus for a comparator anyway. The difference between two `int` values can be bigger than the `int` value range, hence, overflow. As an additional corner case, when the difference is exactly `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, it will be asymmetric. The correct solution would be calling `Integer.compare(s1.num, s2.num)` instead, though, it is a questionable design to let this class implement `Comparator` anyway. Use `new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.num))` to create a set sorted by `num`.

Comment: @Holger You are right, but that's not OP's question, is it? That's why I did not include it in the answer.

Comment: I think, it’s worth pointing out these things, in addition to the answer, instead of letting the OP go, thinking that all their problems were solved.

Comment: @Holger Okay. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The s1 and s2 in `compare(Sorted s1, Sorted s2)` are local variable definitions, you must not confuse them with the definitions in `main()`. It is not defined (algorithmically, only by the implementation) how `TreeSet` compares the two elements.

```
compare(s1, s2) //yields 33
compare(s2, s1) //yields -33
```

---

[`TreeSet`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/8ed8e2b4b90e/src/share/classes/java/util/TreeSet.java#l123) internally uses a [`TreeMap`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/TreeMap.java#l535). `put` calls compare in several places, usually with the element you put into the TreeSet as first element. Therefore `put(s2)`will call `compare(s2, s1)`. See Code excerpt below:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {    
        Entry<K,V> t = root;    
        if (t == null) {
            compare(key, key); // type (and possibly null) check       
            root = new Entry<>(key, value, null);  
            size = 1;
            modCount++;    
            return null;    
        }    
        int cmp;    
        Entry<K,V> parent;    
        // split comparator and comparable paths    
        Comparator<? super K> cpr = comparator;    
        if (cpr != null) {    
            do {
                parent = t;    
                cmp = cpr.compare(key, t.key);    
                if (cmp < 0)   
                    t = t.left;    
                else if (cmp > 0)    
                    t = t.right;    
                else    
                    return t.setValue(value);    
            } while (t != null);    
        }    
        else {   
            if (key == null)    
                throw new NullPointerException();    
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")    
                Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;   
            do {    
                parent = t;    
                cmp = k.compareTo(t.key);    
                if (cmp < 0)
                     t = t.left; 
                else if (cmp > 0)
                    t = t.right;
                else
                    return t.setValue(value);    
            } while (t != null);    
        }    
        Entry<K,V> e = new Entry<>(key, value, parent);    
        if (cmp < 0)
                parent.left = e;    
        else    
            parent.right = e;    
        fixAfterInsertion(e);    
        size++;    
        modCount++;

        return null;
    }
```

Other implementations or methods might have different behaviour.